# Ionic build/run browser or android plugins are not loaded

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I'm struggling with setting up the environment for an Ionic app using Cordova v5.0.

```
$ ionic platform list 
Installed platforms: android 3.6.4, browser 3.5.2.

$ ionic plugin list
com.ionic.keyboard 1.0.4 "Keyboard"
com.msopentech.azure-mobile-services 0.1.4 "Windows Azure Mobile Services"
org.apache.cordova.console 0.2.13 "Console"
org.apache.cordova.device 0.3.0 "Device"
org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser 0.6.0 "InAppBrowser"

$ ionic build browser => build is done ok
$ ionic build android => build is done ok
```

Now, when I go to "platforms\browser\www\plugins" I only have keyboard and device plugin.

Why Azure plugin is not available there? or InAppBrowser? 
Is there a special command to run when adding plugins to and Ionic project? I added the Azure and InAppBrowser using the commands below:

```
$ ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
$ ionic plugin add com.msopentech.azure-mobile-services
```

Also, when I build for Android platform and emulate -> the plugins are loaded ok BUT when I put the apk on my phone (Galaxy SII 4.2.2) I get "WindowsAzure is not defined" which means that the plugin was not loaded ok.

Do I need to add something in the config.xml file?
I don't see there any references for any of the above plugins.

Please help, I'm kind of newbie for this one. On another laptop I installed VS2015 and the builds are done ok but I would like to be able to work with command-prompt.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you tried removing the platform (`ionic platform rm android`) and adding it again (`ionic platform add android`)?

Comment: Are you loading plugin after device is ready ?